# How to check and fix HotReload with MAUI .net 8?

Tags: xamarin, maui, visual-studio-mac

I can't get Hot Reload to work on Visual Studio 2022 Mac with .net 8 and MAUI on either iOS or Android.

It is enabled in the IDE settings:

[image]

And also shows as connected when running:

[image]

But when making a change to a XAML file, nothing happens. There are not errors coming up and I don't know where else next to look.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hot reload does not work with .NET MAUI starter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71957258/hot-reload-does-not-work-with-net-maui-starter-project)

Comment: No, it doesn't - still not working and I cannot figure out what is wrong

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of Visual Studio?

Comment: yes - have the latest version

Comment: This appears to be a problem with Visual Studio. You can go to [Visual Studio for Mac feedback tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2022) to report the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like HotReload currently *only* works when the build configuration is set to "Debug". no other custom build configurations.